# Track to track clearance in Altium

Tags: pcb, altium, design-rules

While designing PCB in Altium, I defined a rule as follows:

Clearance > Track to Track > 20 mils

But I have LQFP100 component, and it has ~8 mils gap between pads. So I can't do routing. How can I draw a path to the pads of the component without changing the rule?

[image]

EDIT: According to Rohat Kılıç's answer, I defined a rule named ''Lora_Spi'' but the problem still persists.

[image]

Comment: Your edit only applies where the first object and the second object match the Net Class, so it wouldnt apply to things outside of it (the pads next to your net, and so on). That said, 20 mils is huge, are you sure you cant use lower values for clearance?

Comment: @WesleyLee, Thank you for return. 20 mils is just an example. I can't do routing to my chip with a larger gap than my chip's pads. This is actually what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I accomplish this by creating a separate set of rules for areas of tighter tolerances. The way I accomplish this is to create a **[room](https://www.altium.com/documentation/altium-designer/working-with-rooms)** in Altium which allows you to create another matching condition for objects inside the room.

A room in a PCB layout is simply a virtual polygonal region which allows for some extra functionality such as design rules checking ([DRC](https://www.altium.com/documentation/altium-designer/pcb-dlg-designrulecheckformdesign-rule-checker-ad)), component layout duplication, and convenient logical grouping.

**To create a room:**

1. Open the `Design` > `Rules` dialog, navigate to the `Placement` category, select `Room Definition` and then `New Rule`.
2. There, click the `Define...` button which will return you to the PCB layout with the cursor ready to place the first point of a polygon. (I find it helpful to set up the desired snapping and grid before defining a room.)
3. Click through the points desired, similar to placing any other polygon. I usually place the room boundaries 1-2 mm outside of the footprint area where I wish to define different tolerances.
4. When completed, the room is given the same name as the rule which defines it.

You can turn on/off room visibility with the **View Options** panel. They are *not* treated as a layer like copper, overlays, and keep-outs.

With the room defined, you can now create additional rules (such as width, clearance, etc.) which use the room as a condition.

**For example, to allow a smaller clearance within the room:**

1. Add a new rule in the `Electrical` > `Clearance` category, and set the `Where the first object matches...` property to use a `Custom Query`.
2. The syntax to use for the custom query is `WithinRoom(<Room Name>)`.
3. For the property `Where the second object matches...`, select the net or net class or leave as `All` as desired.
4. Set the clearance as needed for the room/footprint.
5. Ensure that the new rule has a higher priority than other clearance rules.

**Caveats:**

1. Straight track segments which traverse the room boundary will not be considered as "within" the room, and therefore ignore the rule. You can extend the room boundaries as needed or split the track (`Edit` > `Slice Tracks`) to work around this.
2. Rooms do not move with components, so if you relocate a footprint for which a room was created, you need to remember to move the room as well. (Rooms can optionally move all of the components inside of them, but not the other way around. Also, rooms can be visually distracting/annoying, so it's easy to turn off their visibility, work on the PCB, then realize much later that rooms are in the wrong positions.)

**Visual Example:**

Here is an image showing a room around a connector which I created to allow a smaller clearance between differential tracks and ground within and near the connector footprint:

[image: Room over connector in Altium PCB editor]

The room name is shown in the center red block and its boundaries extend somewhat beyond the connector pads.

Comment: A sensible solution! I think this can solve my problem. I'm busy with another project right now. But I will try what you said as soon as possible. Thanks for your advice!

Comment: I have a problem. When I finish drawing room and right-click the mouse, the room disappears. I can't place the room. Also, when I try to place a room by changing the x1,x2,y1,y2 values ​​in the rule, I cannot change the values.

Comment: @harmonica Rooms can be finicky. If you don't have at least one copper layer enabled/visible, rooms often won't be shown. I think it's an Altium bug. Also double check that room visibility is on; you can create rooms with visibility off and it will create that mystifying "disappearing room" problem as well. I linked the documentation page for Rooms in the answer, so be sure to review that as well.

Comment: When I looked at the documentation page, I saw that the author added the room as Design > Rooms > Rectangular Room or Polygonal Room. I added a room without defining a rule, just like on the document page. And when I looked at the rules again, I saw that the room I drew was defined as a rule. After that, I added a new clearance rule and completed the drawing. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Worked for me. However you cannot have more than one room with the same name. So if you have multiple cases for this issue you cannot solve it with one room name, you would have to add the second room to the rule as well which is annoying. Is there any work around?

Comment: @puncher My first thought was you could use a wildcard to specify (e.g. `ROOM_*` to quality `ROOM_A` and `ROOM_B` but that doesn't work. It appears we will have to continue adding multiple distinct rooms to the design rule,

Answer (score 0):

On the window you set the clearances there's an option named something like "ignore the rules within footprint" (can't remember exact name). If you select it then the clearances will not be applied for the pads on the same footprint. But this doesn't make the tracks routed to/from these pads ignored.

Instead of a global clearance, you can define rules for specific nets (so that some rules apply to only some nets) or exemptions for some nets so that some rules don't apply to these nets. This can be done on the same window using the two drop boxes on top.

Comment: Edited the question.